# Got AttributeError 'User' object has no attribute 'password1'

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, django-views, django-serializer

How to fix the error please help?Got AttributeError 'User' object has no attribute 'password1'.

i want to add two password fields. user is created but error occurs

AttributeError: Got AttributeError when attempting to get a value for field `password1` on serializer `UserSerializer`.
The serializer field might be named incorrectly and not match any attribute or key on the `User` instance.
Original exception text was: 'User' object has no attribute 'password1'.

views.py

```
class RegisterAPIView(generics.CreateAPIView):
    serializer_class = UserSerializer
    queryset = User.objects.all()
```

serializers.py

```
class UserSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    username = serializers.CharField(
        label="Имя пользователя",
        style={"input_type": "username"}
    )
    email = serializers.CharField(
        label="почта",
        style={"input_type": "email"}
    )
    password1 = serializers.CharField(
        label="Пароль",
        style={'input_type': 'password'}
    )
    password2 = serializers.CharField(
        label="Пароль повторно",
        style={'input_type': 'password'}
    )

    def create(self, validated_data):
        password1 = validated_data.pop('password1')
        password2 = validated_data.pop('password2')
        print(validated_data)
        if password1 and password2 and password1 != password2:
            raise ValidationError("Passwords don't match")
        validated_data["password"] = password1
        print(validated_data)
        user = User.objects.create(**validated_data)
        print(user.id)
        return user
```

Comment: seems you have removed `password1` by this line `password1 = validated_data.pop('password1')` and add it with name `password` by this line `validated_data["password"] = password1`

Comment: please provide your User model

Comment: in line " validated_data["password"] = password1" i saved information about the password. The method 'pop()' is removed and return object, so i cant understand ur remark. Could you write about my problem more, please?

Comment: https://prognote.ru/web-dev/back-end/django-registration-via-restapi/

Comment: this site help me write an entry

Answer (score 0):

You need to use **write_only=True** attribute for password1 and password2, Or its better: use a model serializer, use **write_only=True** attribute for password2, override **validate** method for validations, an example:

```
class UserSignUpSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    # or confirm_password field
    password2 = serializers.CharField(write_only=True)

    class Meta:
        model = User # your user model,
        fields = ['username', 'password', 'password2'] # more field you want

    def validate(self, data):
        if data.get('password') != data.get('password2'):
            raise serializers.ValidationError(_("passwords are not same."))
        return data

    def create(self, validated_data):
        validated_data.pop('password2') # you should pop this before create
        user = User.objects.create_user(
            **validated_data
        )
        return user
```